# SMART "power on hours" attribute for different HDD manufacturers

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Is there a table of how to interpret the SMART attribute "power on hours" depending on the HDD manufacturer? Some of them use hours, some minutes or even seconds...

Comment: Good question indeed. I wonder why someone has down-voted it!

Comment: I've never seen a drive that used anything other than hours to represent "power on **hours**"...do you have an example? For instance I have an SSD that stores power on time in milliseconds, but it also _says_ that it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this FAQ answer from the Smartmontools project:

http://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/FAQ#Iseesomestrangeoutputfromsmartctl.Whatdoesitmean

There are links there to vendor specific pages which may provide you with the information you're looking for.

Some other relevant FAQs on the same page:

> **smartctl reports the age as thousands of hours for my
> Maxtor/Hitachi/Fujitsu? disk , yet it is only a few days old**
>
> On recent disks, Maxtor has started to use Attribute 9 to store the
> power-on disk lifetime in minutes rather than hours. In this case, use
> the: '-v 9,minutes' option to correctly display hours and minutes.
>
> Some models of Fujitsu disks use Attribute 9 to store the power-on
> disk lifetime in seconds. In that case, use the: '-v 9,seconds' option
> to correctly display hours, minutes and seconds.
>
> **The power-on timer (Attribute 9 raw value) on my Maxtor disk acts
> strange.**
>
> There are three related problems with Maxtor's SMART firmware:
>
> On some Maxtor disks, the raw value of Attribute 9 (Power On Time) is
> supposed to be minutes. But it advances at an unpredictable rate,
> always more slowly than one count per minute. This is because when the
> disk is in idle mode, the counter stops advancing. This is only
> supposed to happen in standby mode. This will be corrected in Maxtor
> product lines released after October 2004.
>
> In Maxtor disks that use the raw value of Attribute 9 as a minutes
> counter, only two bytes (of the six available) are used to store the
> raw value. So it resets to zero once every 65536=216 minutes, or about
> once every 1092 hours. This is fixed in all Maxtor disks manufactured
> after July 2003, where the raw value was extended to four bytes.
>
> In Maxtor disks that use the raw value of Attribute 9 as a minutes
> counter, the hour time-stamps in the self-test and ATA error logs are
> calculated by right shifting 6 bits. This is equivalent to dividing by
> 64 rather than by 60. As a result, the hour time stamps in these logs
> advance 7% more slowly than they should. Thus, if you do self-tests
> once per week at the same time, instead of the time-stamps being 168
> hours apart, they are 157 hours apart. This is also fixed in all
> Maxtor disks manufactured after July 2003.
>
> **Power_On_Hours Attribute of my new Intel SSD reports ~890000 hours**
>
> This is a bug in Intel 330 Firmware 300i and Intel 520 Firmware 400i.
> The offset is ​894794 hours. See also ticket #289 and ​Intel SSD
> Toolbox SMART Attributes FAQ. The hours counter from Device Statistics
> is not affected: